# How to do map function on vector in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector like (1,100,2,30,20,...)

And what I'd like to do is mapping these value to another value. Actually I can do a loop on these values, but I wonder whether I can make the map function vectorized. For example, I'd like to map the value to its bucket such as following

```
1 ->  "< 10",
20 -> "10 to 50", 
60 -> "50 to 100",
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear or reproducible.  This makes helping difficult.  May I suggest making your question a bit more explicit.

Comment: yes, cut() here should works for this case. But if I'd like to involve more complex logics here, how can I implement a vectorized function ?

Comment: @zjffdu - what 'more complex logics' do you want to implement? Please provide a *specific* example of what you are wishing to do. Otherwise I am guessing that `cut` or `findInterval` or similar functions will be about as good as people can suggest.

Answer (score 4):

What about something like this?

```
test <- c(1,24,2,30,20)

sapply(
    # bin the data up
    findInterval(test,seq(0,30,10)),
    # apply a particular function to the data element
    # dependent on which bin it was put into
    function(x) switch(x,sqrt(x),sin(x),cos(x),tan(x))
    )

[1]  1.0000000 -0.9899925  1.0000000  1.1578213 -0.9899925
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Purrr's `map` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.1.0/topics/map )

e.g.

```
xx=c(1,4,0,3,1)

f = function(s) return(c((10*s):(10*s+9)))
xx %>% map(f)
```